# jQuery will not add CSS, only change CSS if it's already defined by HTML

Tags: jquery, css

Long time reader, first time poster! =)

I am having an issue with jQuery.  I am trying to add a style to each li, however, unless the li already has that specific style defined inline, jQuery will seemingly do nothing.  Which is a fine workaround but defeats the goal of my code.

Here's the example of the problem I am having on codepen. I forked another person's code to try to have jQuery add the animation delay instead of having it hard coded in the HTML. I believe the effect and style only work on Chrome.

http://codepen.io/LetsBeNew/pen/qIuah

As you can see I have the first few li elements with inline styles.  jQuery changes these correctly, but does not add styles to the other li elements.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `LI`s that don't have inline styles finish animating (or at least start animating) before the `$(document).ready()` function executes. Compare to this other codepen thingie:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/padfb

All the `LI`s get the border width and the increased animation delay to 10 seconds. Except of the one with the `coral` class, which has a very small delay (zero in this case). In your case every `LI` without an inline style value for the delay got a zero by default, which caused it to start animating before the document ready function had a chance to change the values.

In the codepen I linked above I put to numbers you can play with to see the effects. they are `play1` in the HTML source (coral LI), and `play2` in the CSS source (last of the LI rule attributes).

Comment: Ah! I think you are right, about the animation finishing before the jQuery can change it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the jquery that would manipulate css in your example... on that note, .css should work just fine: http://api.jquery.com/css/